# HaxeFlixel Failing To Compile To HTML5

Tags: haxeflixel

I Just Finished Up My HaxeFlixel Game, So Naturally I Tried To Compiled It. It Was Going To Be A HTML5 Web Game But When I Tried To Compiled It But It Came Up With This.

```
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/polymod/git/polymod/format/XMLMerge.hx:189: characters 10-23 : Warning : This typedef is depreca
ted in favor of haxe.xml.Access
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/polymod/git/polymod/format/XMLMerge.hx:189: characters 30-43 : Warning : This typedef is depreca
ted in favor of haxe.xml.Access
source/CoolUtil.hx:34: characters 30-34 : Type not found : File
source/DifficultyIcons.hx:38: characters 11-21 : Type not found : FileSystem
source/DifficultyIcons.hx:44: characters 11-21 : Type not found : FileSystem
source/HealthIcon.hx:86: characters 9-19 : Type not found : FileSystem
source/SortState.hx:147: characters 7-11 : Type not found : File
source/SortState.hx:155: characters 7-11 : Type not found : File
source/SortState.hx:167: characters 28-32 : Type not found : File
source/SortState.hx:168: characters 29-33 : Type not found : File
source/SortState.hx:176: characters 8-12 : Type not found : File
source/SortState.hx:177: characters 8-12 : Type not found : File
source/SortState.hx:179: characters 7-11 : Type not found : File
source/FreeplayState.hx:176: characters 9-19 : Type not found : FileSystem
source/ModifierState.hx:12: characters 8-19 : You cannot access the sys package while targeting js (for sys.io.File)
source/FreeplayState.hx:187: characters 4-17 :     referenced here
```

Any Tips On How To Fix This?

Answer (score 0):

I presume your trying to compile FNF, but that is just a guess based on the error messages.

In reference to your first error, are you using latest Haxe version because hxFixel does not yet support it and I suspect polymod is using the older Fast xml access rather than newer. So make sure you have older haxe version installed to support hxFixel and OpenFL.

https://github.com/larsiusprime/polymod/blob/master/polymod/format/XMLMerge.hx#L189

Note that Polymod is setup to work with any haxe target as long as it provides a file system, html5 does not provide a file system, so unless your targetting nodejs ( and even if ) you can't use sys package code. You can load files in html5 but it does not allow you to do some of the stuff that Polymod provides, and access inside OpenFl/hxFixel will be different.

My guess is that you can compile FNF without 'mod' tools, but likely you will need to explore the code deeper yourself, it looks like it's setup for haxe c++ target.

Apologise if my guesses are wrong - you really need to provide deeper context ( link to some of the sources ) to get any proper help, but maybe my comments were useful?

Comment: nvm it was my antivirus lmao